# Override the Authorization header with XHR after the browser shows the authentication popup

Tags: javascript, authentication, xmlhttprequest

In a JavaScript web app I authorize with a server using XMLHttpRequest and setting the "Authorization" header via `setRequestHeader`.

That usually works fine. But sometimes I manage to somehow end up with the browser popping up an "authentication" dialog requesting me to input a username and password (this is caused by an 401 response of the server).

From this point on, I am unable to set the "Authorization" header via XHR. It will always be set to the value, created from the data I put into the popup from the browser.

I find this very strange. Is the "Authorization" header somehow restricted? Can I override it?

Comment: I solved the problem by making the server never return 401. I do not have the problem anymore, but of course the question is not answered ...